# React Native AsyncStorage

Tags: arrays, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to save houses in an array using AsyncStorage. Each array element represents a house Object. And each house object has a latitude, longitude and a house number. I am not sure how to go about representing this. It seems to me that AsyncStorage is not well-suited for saving dynamic objects that can be updated programmatically. 
I want to be able to add more houses and delete some houses. Basically what I am trying to do is bookmark some houses and delete them from the bookmarks when the user clicks.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: I upvoted your question back to zero :) It is a wall of text, but I think it is a smart question given how AsyncStorage is documented in the RN docs. You have to store strings, but you can actually stringify them and merge updated fields, see `AsyncStorage.mergeItem()`. The answer to your question is also very well-done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncStorage is absolutely perfect for this.

Starting with the structure of your *houses*, I would create an Array which stores objects representing an individual house.

```
const houses = [
  {
    number: 1,
    latitude: 51.5033,
    longitude: -0.119519
  }
]
```

**Saving to AsyncStorage**

When you want to write your collection to `AsyncStorage`, you would do so like this:

```
AsyncStorage
  .setItem('@houses', JSON.stringify(houses))
  .then(houses => console.log(houses)
```

> static setItem(key: string, value: string, callback?: ?(error: ?Error) => void)

*You can also use `async/await` if your project is set up to support it.*

**Reading from AsyncStorage**

Reading your collection back from `AsyncStorage` is simply done via:

```
AsyncStorage
  .getItem('@houses')
  .then(houses => console.log(JSON.parse(houses)))
```

You could set the response in your state, do as you please.

**Deleting a specific house**

This depends entirely on how you set your app up. Are you going to `map` through each house and create a list component for example?

[image]

(Sorry about losing the border on the right)

If so, you could:

```
houses.map(house => (
  <View>
   <Text>Number: {house.number}</Text>
   <Text>Latitude: {house.latitude}</Text>
   <Text>Longitude: {house.longitude</Text>
   <Button onPress={() => this.deleteHouse(house.number)}/>
  </View>
));
```

Then create a `deleteHouse` function which will handle it.

```
const deleteHouse = (number) => {
  const { houses } = this.state; // Assuming you set state as previously mentioned
  const newHouses = houses.filter((house) => house.number != number);
  this.setState({houses: newHouses}, () => saveHouses);
}
```

And finally a `saveHouses` to sync it back to AsyncStorage. The function will clear AsyncStorage and then save the new houses.

```
const saveHouses = () => {
  const { houses } = state;
  AsyncStorage
    .removeItem('@houses')
    .then(() => {
      AsyncStorage
        .setItem('@houses', JSON.stringify(houses))
        .then(houses => console.log(houses)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Sqlite alternative like [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/), it's free, fast and easy to code, with this you will save tons of hours of work, also as you need, you can make queries, update and delete objects.