# How can save value of response json data to AsyncStorage?

Tags: json, react-native

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props) 
  this.state = { 
    UserEmail: '',
    UserPassword: '' 
  } 
} 

UserLoginFunction = () => { 
  const { UserEmail }  = this.state;
  const { UserPassword }  = this.state; 
  axios.post(`Login`, { 
    username: this.state.UserEmail, 
    password: this.state.UserPassword
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);    
  }); 
}
```

Response:

> [{"return_type":"true","role_id":"1","users_id":"1","manpower_id":"1","message":"Success"}]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native AsyncStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105876/react-native-asyncstorage)

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage works with String.
You need to save:

```
JSON.stringify(response.data)
```

in it.

something like this:

```
const data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('key or any name you want', data);
```